# How to permanently disable http_proxy

Tags: proxy, environment-variables

When I remove proxy from System/Network and apply it system wide it still remains when working in console. When I run:

```
env | grep proxy
```

it prints:

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.studnet.lan:8080
ftp_proxy=ftp://proxy.studnet.lan:8080
socks_proxy=socks://proxy.studnet.lan:8080
https_proxy=https://proxy.studnet.lan:8080
```

I could remove it with:

```
unset http_proxy
unset ftp_proxy
unset socks_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

but it's not permanent, when I reopen terminal these proxy variables are again setted.

How to remove them permanently?

Comment: "When I remove proxy from System/Network" Do you mean emptying the text boxes or changing the dropdown menu to "none"?

Comment: @jackweirdy, changing dropdown menu to none.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be sure to change the method dropdown from "manual" to "none". This will erase everything - you may need to restart the machine after doing this.

Comment: You are right, it removes. Even better I don't need to restart computer, just to log off and then log on.

Comment: Very handy. My proxy settings from Charles Proxy seemed to get "stuck" even after i closed the session and quit the program.  I did this (using ```gsettings``` on the command line instead of the Network Manager proxy gui: ```gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none' ``` , logged off and on and the ```http_proxy``` variable was unset for good. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that those variables are not declared in any of the below files:

- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `/etc/environment`

If they are, it'd be better if you remove those lines.

However, if you're unable to find them, then put the `unset` lines you've mentioned in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: You are right, they are in `/etc/environment`. I found solution for another problem I had with proxy. It's username and password for proxy. I couldn't use wget or ruby gem installing through proxy, because of authentication error.
I just wrote settings in format: `username:password@proxy.example.com` for `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and it works now.
Thanks man, you saved me a lot of nerves :)

Comment: Glad it worked. :)

Comment: Thank you so much :D i got these settings into /etc/environment. I usually use .bashrc so didn't figure how much files are interfering that.

Comment: When I do `env | grep proxy` I get the same results as op but `/etc/environment` is empty. How do I find those variables?

Comment: Life saver! It took me a day to find the variables in `/etc/environment`.