# Unable removing proxy from ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, proxy

**Please help  I can not remove proxy in my ubuntu terminal .I want download  cppcheck for sublime or any other software. but it is showing error like this . the internet is working fine in web browser but it is showing error in only ubuntu terminal.**

**This is the Image of the error** 
[deleted]

Comment: Please don't provide terminal output as images. It is difficult for responders to use part of the output in their answers or in requests for clarification. Instead, copy and paste the relevant output here using this site's [markdown formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Also, you have `268 not upgraded`. You need to fix that **first**.

Comment: Firstly, try `sudo apt upgrade -y` to see if you can upgrade packages. If you have a proxy enabled, [try this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251003/how-to-permanently-disable-http-proxy) to disable it.

Comment: I have tried many possible ways which I have found but still not solve  unsetting proxy.so suggest any other solution.