# How to permanently disable proxies from terminal in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, proxy

I tried to unset the proxies using `unset all_proxy && unset ALL_PROXY && unset socks_proxy && unset http_proxy && unset https_proxy && unset ftp_proxy` command, but it unset these variables temporarily. They keep on coming once I restart the terminal.

I looked at the answers of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251003/how-to-permanently-disable-http-proxy) questions but it doesn't work in my case. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: didnt you find any of those entries in the files mentioned

Comment: I got it now. Those entries were there in `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. Initially, I had just checked the `~/.bashrc` file. Thanks a lot.